# I want to show customers phone_number and coin in home page

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fetch customers phone_number & Coin from the DB to my home page But I am stuck here and got really confused about this topic.I tried request.session.customer but it only shows the customers ID.

Here is my Customer Models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    email = models.EmailField( default=1)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coin = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Here is views.py

class Index(View):

```
def get(self, request):
        
        
        cart = request.session.get('cart')

        if not cart:
            request.session['cart'] = {}



        #products = None
        products = Product.get_all_products()
        cats = Category.get_categories()
        brands = Brand.get_brands()
        sliders = Slider.objects.all()
        offers = Offer.objects.all()

#       balance = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        
        # balance = get_object_or_404(Customer, coin = request.coin)
        

        categoryID = request.GET.get('category')
        brandID = request.GET.get('brand')

        if categoryID:
            # products = Product.get_products_by_category(categoryID)
            products = products.filter(category__id = categoryID)

        # else:
        #   products = Product.get_all_products()

        if brandID:
            # proucts = Product.get_brands_by_products(brandID)
            products = products.filter(brand__id = brandID)
            
        # else:
        #   products = Product.get_all_products()

        args = {
        'products':products,
        'cats': cats,
        'brands': brands,
        'sliders':sliders,
        'offers':offers,
        # 'balance':balance 
        }
        return render(request, 'Home/index.html', args)
```

Balance:{{request.session.customer}}C 
I commented somelines to show only coin in homepage but its not showing :(

Comment: 1) show your index.html 2) in your view ->args, you did not have customer, so how can you get coin which is associated with customer?

Comment: i commented that line cz i was not getting coin :(